# C# List sorting explanation needed

Tags: c#, list, sorting

I have a problem which is already solved, but I don't know what really happens. Here is the simplified task: I have a list of records. The records consists of 2 fields, a `key` and a `value`. All keys are different. I want to sort them, so

- I have a row with empty string as `key`, that should be in the first place.
- The come the rows in which the `value` contains "Key not found" in alphabetical order by `key`
- Then the rest of the rows in alphabetical order by `key`.

So I made this class:

```
private class RecordComparer : IComparer<GridRecord>
        {
            public int Compare(GridRecord x, GridRecord y)
            {
                if (x.Key == String.Empty)
                    return -1;
                else if (y.Key == String.Empty)
                    return 1;
                else if (x.Value.Contains("Key not found:") && !y.Value.Contains("Key not found:"))
                    return -1;
                else if (!x.Value.Contains("Key not found:") && y.Value.Contains("Key not found:"))
                    return 1;
                else return (x.Key.CompareTo(y.Key));
            }
        }
```

When I try to use it, I got `Comparer (or the IComparable methods it relies upon) did not return zero when Array.Sort called x. CompareTo(x). x: ''  x's type: 'GridRecord' The IComparer:`
The error doesn't always appear, sometimes(usually when I use it first time in my program) it works fine. Second or third call crashes.

Inserting

```
if (x.Key == y.Key)
     return 0;
```

in the begginning of the Compare function above solved the problem, everything works fine. Why?

Answer (score 1):

If you compare `{Key=""}` with anything, you are currently returning `-1`. Even if you are comparing it **with itself**. When you compare something with itself (or something semantically equivalent to the same), you are supposed to return `0`. That is what the error is about.

Comment: I understand this. It was in the error message. I just dont know why is something compared to itself while sorting and why is it working sometimes.

Comment: @gkovacs90 Sometimes you're sorting data that has distinct items, and sometimes you're sorting data that doesn't.

Comment: @Servy All the keys are different in theese cases

Comment: @gkovacs90 Apparently not.

Comment: @gkovacs90 which elements it ends up comparing to which other elements is hugely dependent on the sort algorithm, the day of the week, the alignment of Mars relative to Venus, and the number of cats that have crossed your path that day.

Comment: @MarcGravell The sort algorithm is `List<T>.Sort`. As I know it is a quicksort which doesn't compare an element to itself.

Comment: @gkovacs90 the error is telling you that yes: it did compare an element to itself; it explicitly says so, here: `x.CompareTo(x)`

Comment: Yes it does. So the question: why does it work always when I try it first time? I mean I sort listA - correct, then listB - correct, then listA again - error. Same if I go with listB-listC-listA. We can say the sorting algorithm use some randomized implementeation of quicksort, which compares an element to itself sometimes. But why does it work first time always correctly?

Answer (score 0):

It is wise to enforce total order in your custom comparer. One of the requirements for total order is reflexivity: for any `x` `Compare(x, x)` must be equal to zero. This property is required, for example, when comparer is used to sort an array with non-unique values.

Some libraries may do additional checks for custom comparers. There is no point to compare the element to itself, but on the other hand such check allow the runtime to find subtle errors (like the one you made). Probably thats why you've got your error message. Fixing such errors makes your code more stable. Usually the checks like this exist in debug builds only.